# Weyl and Majorana-Weyl spinors why need commutation?

Tags: special-relativity, representation-theory, dirac-equation, spinors, clifford-algebra

Let $\psi$ denote a Dirac spinor then Weyl spinors are defined by:
$$\psi_{L,R}=\frac{1}{2} (I\pm \gamma)\psi$$
on even dimensions $\gamma$ commutes with $\sigma_{\mu \nu}$ (generators used to define spinor rep) and as such this is clearly a subrep of the dirac spinors. But I don't understand why it is then claimed what we can't define Weyl spinors for odd dimensions. Might it also be true that $\psi_{L,R}$ form a subrep in this case - even if less explicitly?

On a related note Majorana-Weyl spinors are said to only exist in $2 \mod 8$ dimensions which is derived on the condition that:
$$[\gamma, C]=0$$
but I cannot see why this needs to be true. Since surely we only need them to share a single eigenvector rather then all of them (c.f. this [post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/144392/condition-for-two-matrices-to-share-at-least-one-eigenvector)).

Please can someone explain these two points?

<sub>Note on Notation: $\gamma=i^{-k}\gamma_0 \ldots \gamma_{d-1}$ and $C$ is the operator for which Majorana spinors are defined: $\psi =C\psi$</sub>

Comment: I think I have found the answer to the first of these, i.e. in the odd case $\gamma\propto 1 $ so the projector simply projects back onto the Dirac spinors or $0$ and in either case a trivial subrep. I am still confused about the second part.

Comment: I have found H. Murayama’s notes: http://hitoshi.berkeley.edu/230A/clifford.pdf to be a good and clear  intro to the eightfold periodicty of Majorana and Weyl fermions. You want to look at, and understand the origin of,  his table 4 for Minkowski signature.

Comment: Appendix E of de Wit, B. and Smith, J. (1986), *Field Theory in Particle Physics* (North-Holland Personal Library), V1,  ISBN 978-0444869999 should [do the trick](http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~wit00103/ftip/AppendixE.pdf).

Comment: If mathematically inclined, peruse the [Clifford algebra clock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classification_of_Clifford_algebras).

Comment: You seem to have taken an alarming and mysterious left turn with your oracular "surely we only need them to share a single eigenvector rather than all of them".  I doubt your question is meaningful, unless you explain this preposterous misconception.